# Which ODBC driver should I use for SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, odbc, connection-string

There is a param on ODBC connection strings called Driver.
My old application always used `{SQL Driver}` and I know there is `{SQL Native Client}` and others.

My questions are:

- What is the difference between these types of Drivers?
- When do I should use one or another?
- I'm not defining a Provider on my connection. Should I?
- What is the best way to configure my connection string?

I'm using SQL Server 2005 Standard

Comment: Hmm How long is a connection string? ;)

Comment: This question is way too open ended.